# Can one use etoc with amsart?

Tags: amsart, etoc

A [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423020/how-do-you-make-tocs-for-each-section-and-subsection-in-amsart) was suddenly deleted which had led me investigate if etoc was compatible with amsart. The answer is that it needs a little of tuning up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `etoc` package is not out-of-the box compatible with amsart:

- there seems to be a problem with 
  `\@mkboth {\MakeUppercase \contentsname}{\MakeUppercase \contentsname}`
  which etoc does by default from code of the article class,
- besides, copied pasted from amsart doc

  ```
  In amsart.sty \@startsection, \@sect, and a couple of other things are rede-
  fined to fix a few hard-coded things that would interfere with the desired style.
  The most noteworthy difference is that all section headings will go into the table
  of contents (governed by secnumdepth as usual), EVEN WHEN THE * FORM
  IS USED. The only section heading not listed in the table of contents is the
  heading for the toc itself.
  ```

These two things can be handled by overwriting `etoc`'s default behaviour of the "toc display style", to avoid the `\@mkboth` and to avoid the usage of `\section*` because this creates an unwanted entry in the toc file. Thus, this minimal example works for me:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsettocstyle{\noindent\textbf{\contentsname}\par}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{FOO}

\etocsettocstyle{\noindent\textbf{Local table of contents}\par}{}
\localtableofcontents

\subsection{bar1}
\subsection{bar2}
\subsection{bar3}

\section{FOOII}

\end{document}
```

[image]